# Numerical solution of quantum harmonic oscillator blows up

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

When i try to plot the numerical solution of quantum harmonic oscillator , it blows up even for the correct energies. Why does this happen and how can it be fixed? The code i used is as following.

```
sol = 
  First[
    NDSolve[
      {-1/2 D[ψ[x], {x, 2}] + 1/2 x^2 ψ[x] == (1 + 1/2) ψ[x], 
       ψ[0] == 0, ψ'[0] == 1}, 
      ψ[x], {x, -a, a}], 
      MaxSteps -> 10000000] 

Plot[ψ[x] /. sol, {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> 1]
```

Comment: What is the numerical value for `a`?

Comment: typically it is 10 but you can play around with it

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to get the solution that's decaying very sharply (Gaussian times a Hermite polynomial); increasing `WorkingPrecision` will delay this, but you'll hit the effect at even higher values of `a`. BTW, this ODE can be solved by `DSolve[]`.

Comment: Yes it can be solved by DSolve but i wanted to write c programm to solve it numerically and for that is used NDSolve just to see what kind of behavior is expected from numerical solutions. Can i change the method of solving this ODE in mathematica to get better results.

Comment: It's kind of an inherent property of such DEs: when your DE has a growing and a decaying solution, the result of a numerical integration method is actually some linear combination of those solutions, where the coefficients multiplying the growing solution are hopefully small. So, a numerical solution will be fine over a small-ish interval, but will certainly blow up past it. This is even more of a problem if you'll be doing it in C, since you don't have arbitrary precision there (usually).

Comment: Note that you've set `MaxSteps->` inside of `First`, not `NDSolve[]`, you might also be interested in `NDSolveValue[]`

Comment: `, WorkingPrecision -> 50` gives you an accurate plot for the entire domain given. But like @J.M. said, this won't help you in `C`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has no solution other than the partial fixes mentioned in the comments.